# command-line cURL to PHP doesn't work?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to convert command-line cURL to PHP cURL, but it doesn't seem to work when I do it through PHP. I access the same URL and everything, but the API returns a general error with no data.

This works properly, it is accessed via POST with no post body, just parameters in the URL.

```
$curlRequest = 'curl -X POST -d "" --globoff \''.$baseURL.'?access_key='.$access_key.'&handles='.$handles.'&contextToken='.$contextToken.'&access_sig='.$access_sig.'\'';

exec($curlRequest, $result);
```

However, when I try to perform the same request with the cURL library in PHP, it doesn't work.

```
$url = $baseURL.'?access_key='.$access_key.'&handles='.$handles.'&contextToken='.$contextToken.'&access_sig='.$access_sig.'\'';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

`$server_output` just ends up being an empty error from the API instead of the same data that the first code block returns. Am I doing something incorrectly? Are the two requests not equivalent?

Comment: Why not simplify to `urlencode(json_encode($param2))` instead of doing your own replacements?

Comment: When I use `urlencode` with `$url` in the curl URL, `$server_output` is empty. I'm not sure why.